# Why is computedFee too small when using calculateComputedFee function?

Tags: javascript, function, ethereum

I tried to calculate computedFee according to this page: https://www.metacrypt.org/tools/uniswap-v3-calculator-simulator/?network=ethereum&token0=0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2&token1=0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48&feeTier=3000 But computedFee is 1.8282539706741483e-21, which is too small.

```
function calculateComputedFee(){
//poolID: 0x8ad599c3a0ff1de082011efddc58f1908eb6e6d8

const feeTier = 0.003;
const volumeUSD = 6631238.50;
const existingLiquidity = 283207208.65;
const depositAmount = 1000; // dollar

// These values depend on the token pair and the price range
const ethPrice = 1800; // dollar
const amount0 = depositAmount / 2; // amount of token0 to deposit
const amount1 = (depositAmount / 2) / ethPrice ; // amount of token1 to deposit
const sqrtRatioAX96 = 146144307145949320; // lower bound of the price range
const sqrtRatioBX96 = 156816964661737472; // upper bound of the price range
const P = 1870.596264329329820965675342457762; // current price
const Pa = 1649.0832769175609; // lower bound of the price range in terms of price
const Pb = 1974.6659682730651; // upper bound of the price range in terms of price

// Calculate user liquidity
const liquidity0 = amount0 * (sqrtRatioBX96 * sqrtRatioAX96) / (sqrtRatioBX96 - sqrtRatioAX96);
const liquidity1 = amount1 / (sqrtRatioBX96 - sqrtRatioAX96);

let userTotalLiquidity;
if (P <= Pa) {
  userTotalLiquidity = liquidity0;
} else if (Pa < P && P < Pb) {
  userTotalLiquidity = Math.min(liquidity0, liquidity1);
} else if (P >= Pb) {
  userTotalLiquidity = liquidity1;
}

// Calculate computed fee
const computedFee = feeTier * volumeUSD * (userTotalLiquidity / (existingLiquidity + userTotalLiquidity));
console.log(computedFee);
}
```

I think I set the variables amount0, amount1, sqrtRatioAX96, sqrtRatioBX96, P, Pa, Pb incorrectly, but I don’t know where the error is in the process of calculating computedFee. Please refer to https://www.metacrypt.org/tools/uniswap-v3-calculator-simulator/?network=ethereum&token0=0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2&token1=0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48&feeTier=3000 for reference.